# Is there a way to skip the header line while sqoop export the csv file to Vertica DB

Tags: sqoop, vertica

I need to sqoop export the csv file to vertica, But since csv has header in it, that line as well gets exported.
Is there any efficient way to avoid the header

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sqoop completely. But if sqoop can control the generation of the Vertica copy command, make sure, with a CSV file like this:

```
id|name
 1|Arthur
 2|Ford
 3|Zaphod
```

to generate this command:

```
COPY public.foo FROM LOCAL 'foo.csv' DELIMITER '|' SKIP 1
```

`SKIP 1` is the clause that makes `COPY` skip the first line.